# Socket io Client in ReactJS is getting multiple emits from the server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am building a chat room with some extra features, and I have a socket io server, as well as a socket io client in ReactJS.

I have it so if someone pins a message or changes the settings of the chat room, it emits the changes to the server, the server saves those changes, and then emits them back out to everyone so everyone is synced.

The settings and pinned messages successfully transfer and are communicated, I have console.logs at almost every step of the transfer, the client logs out a single request, the server logs that it emits a single time, but the client logs that it recieved an emit multiple times, sometimes a couple of times like 2-6 requests, sometime it gives out 60 requests. I'm trying to really control the efficiency, but I have no idea what is causing this

I'm not sure it matters but another thing of note is that the client also connects to a native WebSocket server to get messages from another source

what the client generally looks like is:

```
effect(()=>{
  socket.emit('changeSetting', setting)
},[setting])

socket.on('recieveSetting', (arg)=>{
  if(arg != setting){
    setSetting(arg);
  }
})
```

the server then looks like this:

```
socket.on('changeSetting', (arg)=>{
  storedSetting = arg
  socket.emit('recieveSetting', storedSetting)
})
```

That's the general structure, so I don't think its an issue of the code, more like if reactJS or connecting to the other websocket causes it to get multiple emits

Comment: Maybe you're getting stuck in some sort of loop. Where the client sends `changeSetting` to the server. The server sends `receiveSetting` back which subsequently triggers `changeSetting` again.

Comment: Socket.io has a way to emit to all clients in a room except for the sender. You should make sure you're using that if you don't want to trigger some sort of loop.